# Need advice on image resizing and display for Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image

I'll start by explaining what I would like to do.

I have an image gallery grid layout page with thumbnails. Each thumbnail image is to be the same size, say 120px x 80px. I would like to display all the images on page load and more as a user scrolls down on the page. There will be hover and click states for individual images in the grid where the full size image pops up to display in a lightbox.

1. What solutions (gems, techniques, etc.) are there for loading images that are larger (1024 x 768) into my database (Photo) model such that I can generate a small thumbnail image of predefined smaller size?
2. Is the best way to load a whole page of small images if my goal is to allow more to load as the user scrolls down on the page? Or should I load only what the user sees, then use AJAX to load more as they scroll down?
3. Is Paperclip a common solution in this case? I'm looking into this and CarrierWave on RailsCasts.
4. If using something like Paperclip, can it handle cropping an image that isn't the same aspect ratio as others? ie, scale and crop a square image the same as a rectangle image to a defined size.

I'm new to handling a large number of images in a rails application and appreciate any advice, books, tutorials, techniques people are familiar with out there.

Thanks!

Comment: I personally use https://github.com/jnicklas/carrierwave/ and if you want resource, books...etc you can take a look to https://github.com/jnicklas/carrierwave/wiki

Comment: There's also [Dragonfly](https://github.com/markevans/dragonfly), which can do dynamic resizing and various other ImageMagick transforms.

Answer (score 0):

1) I prefer paperclip, though this may be due to less experience with other gems.

2) Generally, the best way to handle lots of images on a page is with sprite sheets.  If the images on the page are always going to be the same, this might be a good option.  If you are doing something with infinite scrolling, ajax is the way to go ([railscast on infinite scrolling](http://railscasts.com/episodes/114-endless-page-revised))

3) I'm not sure if paperclip is a common solution, but it certainly is one that you should consider.

4) Yes, [cropping works in paperclip](http://viget.com/extend/manual-cropping-with-paperclip).